# Interface Builderで作ったTableViewでセルの設定ができない

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xib

`Xib`で`UIView`を作り、その上に`TableView`を乗せて、その`TableView`に`TableViewCell`を乗せようとするのですが、キレイにセルが乗らずうまくいきません。また、`attributes inspector`にも`Content`と`Prototype Cells`の項目がありません。`Xib`では`TableView`を扱うことができないのでしょうか？
どなたか分かる方がいれば教えていただきたいです。
すみませんが、よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

InterfaceBuilderには、StoryBoardのカスタムセルを作成する機能はありません。

`UITableViewCell`は`initWithStyle:`を用いて組み込みのスタイルを利用するか、`UITableViewCell`のみの`xib`を別途作成し、`tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`で`UINib`から生成するというのが昔のパターンでした。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。やはりXibではTableViewを扱うことはできないのですね。コードでTableViewを生成するやり方にしたいと思います。ありがとうございました。